# Create a number formatting that changed based on another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, formatting

I would like to be able to change the number formatting of multiple cells based another cell. The goal would be to switch from absolute to percentage values and vice versa. By using the conditional formatting and the formula, I achieve to effectively put % **but the number formatting however stays "General". And I want it to be "Percentage"**.

Here some picture to explain the problem.

[image]

You can see that the formula is "If D3 = "%" then number formatting is percentage. Even though there is indeed a "%" at the end of my number, I want them to really switch to the "Percentage" number formatting and not stay "General".

[image]

Later on, the goal would be to take this values and put them in a graph. However, if the values of the cells stays "general" and not "percentage" then the graph doesn't show percentage values but always absolute values.

Hope someone can help this (quite complex) excel problem!

Comment: I've checked it in Excel, and this is what I've found: the number formatting in those cells is actually PERCENTAGE. What you seed in the menu, is not the actual status, but the setting BEFORE CONDITIONAL FORMATTING is applied. Also if you set a conditional formatting for e.g. bold underlined, your cells will be formatted correctly when condition is true, but you won't see the changes in the ribbon.

Comment: Problem is, when you take those data and want to create a graph with it, they won't be in percentage. I don't think it's possible to change it without VBA (check my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer thanks to one of my colleague.

The trick is not possible without using a VBA code. Here it is:

```
If Range("B2") = "%" Then
        Range("E5:N16").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
```

ps: to activate VBA, press alt + F11 in Excel (just a reminder for some, or a first time for others, just like me)